# Need to limit the size of UITextField independent of length of text and editing of text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xib

Is there a way to limit the frame size of a `UITextField` after calling setText?  All other questions seem to pertain to adjusting the size based on the string after user editing, or limiting the size of the string itself while editing.

The UITextField is initialized from IB, then in viewDidLoad I call setText.  The `UITextField` is a `UINavigationItem` on a `UINavigationBar`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/ThisIsABogusURLForExamplePurposes.htm"];
    [_addressBar setText:theURL];
}
```

In this case I do need the user to be able to edit the string but it's also set in code the first time the view is presented.  In IB I have set the width to the desired maximum width and if I populate the `UITextField` with a small string it remains that size.  However, calling setText with any string that results in text appearing beyond the width of the field, causes it to stretch the `UITextField` width to the full length of the `UINavigationBar`.  I have tried to programmatically set the frame size of the field after setText is called but it seems to have no effect.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would using the textField placeholder be sufficient instead of setting the textField value?

Comment: Unfortunately, `setPlaceholder:` has the same effect.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem unfortunately. When using a placeholder, the text field behaves as expected by adding ellipses to indicate the additional text that is not visible.

Comment: Hmm, UITextField was created a while ago with IB, not sure why this would matter but there must be a setting i have wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I have not been able to solve it using interface builder. What I did is add the addressbar with a fixed size programmatically to a UIView of a certain size. This UIView is then set as the titleView of the navigation item.

This left-aligns the textfield, and will recalculate its placement again when you rotate the device (thats why I overrided viewWillLayoutSubviews).

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/thisIsABogusURLForExamplePurposes.htm"];

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 30.0)];
    UITextField *addressBar = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
    [addressBar setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [addressBar setText:theURL];

    [containerView addSubview:addressBar];
    [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:containerView];
}
```

Comment: My view only supports portrait. As long as the user can still enter a string longer than the size of the container view and see the cursor while typing this will work for me (container view being the titleview). Will try this tonight.

Comment: worked like a charm, in fact simply added a UIView in IB as the titleView in the navBar, put the existing UITextView inside, done.